# Is it possible to make text blink inside vim?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

There are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (namely 5 and 6) that make subsequent text blink and my terminal (rxvt-unicode-256color) does support this.

Is there a way to allow this to happen using `hi`?

*EDIT:* From the [manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#term-list):

> start={term-list} *highlight-start* *E422*
>   stop={term-list}  *term-list* *highlight-stop*
>
> **These lists of terminal codes can be used to get non-standard attributes on a terminal.**
>
> The escape sequence specified with the "start" argument     is written
>   before the characters in the highlighted  area.  **It can be anything
>   that you want to send to the  terminal to highlight this area**.  The
>   escape sequence   specified with the "stop" argument is written after
>   the   highlighted area.  This should undo the "start" argument.
>     Otherwise the screen will look messed up.

I supposed this could be what I was looking for therefore I tried the following:

```
hi foo start=t_mb stop=<ESC>[0m`<br>
```

Nothing happened however (and I did make sure `foo` matches the `sy[ntax]` rule)
I tried making the text bold in similar fashion (by using `t_md` instead of `t_mb`) but it did not work (bold does work with `cterm=bold` though).

I either misunderstood what `start` and `stop` actually do or the line above simply shows incorrect usage.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *possible* to do this using the `start` and `stop` arguments to the `:highlight` command as you suggest, but you're probably not going to like the trade-off required.

It seems those arguments only work if Vim believes it is running in a black and white terminal (i.e. if `t_Co` is set to `1`).

I found the following info [in a newsgroup posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/fc5h7N35H4o):

> Based on the [code](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FZyX-I%2Fvim%2Fblob%2F6b82591127b58b9ef03790cb51e867b4fd575622%2Fsrc%2Fscreen.c%23L7862&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH331h_JPnBiY0qifuYP7wqBNL--g) I think it never supposed to work if t_Co is
>   greater then 1. But for some reason I do not see this working when
>   t_Co is 1 and setting start/stop for Normal highlight group. Other
>   groups (tested on NonText only) seem to be fine. Though `hi Normal
>   term=bold` neither works with t_Co set to 1.
>
> So this feature is intended for black and white terminals and works
>   there. And it is documented: open `:h highlight-start` and scroll up
>   to “1. highlight arguments for normal terminals”. Higher there is some
>   explanation what is normal and color terminal, though I would say
>   rather strange explanation (while vt100 may be black-and-white (at
>   least its entry does not state it supports any colors) xterm termcap
>   entry states it supports 8 colors (256 colors is supported by
>   xterm-256colors)).

Indeed, I tried using the following command to use the ANSI blink escape sequence:

```
:highlight Blinking start=<esc>[5m stop=<esc>[0m
```

It had no effect. However running the following resulted in blinking text, as expected:

```
:set t_Co=1
:highlight Blinking start=<esc>[5m stop=<esc>[0m
```

Note that if you are dead set on having blinking *and* coloured text at the same time in Vim, you could also use the same highlight arguments to provide colouring even with `t_Co` set to `1`. e.g. the following results in blinking red text:

```
:highlight Blinking start=<esc>[31;5m stop=<esc>[0m
```